# How to share the set statements between insert() and onConflict()?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

As you can see in the example below, a lot of my `set` statements are duplicated between the insert and update clauses.
Is there some way I can factor out the duplicated `set` statements to a shared block of code?

I'm thinking something like how it's pretty simple to factor out parts of a `where` clause by using `DSL.condition()`?

```
db.insertInto(RAID_V2).
  set(RAID_V2.HANDLE, handle).
  set(RAID_V2.SERVICE_POINT_ID, servicePointId).
  set(RAID_V2.URL, raidUrl).
  set(RAID_V2.URL_INDEX, urlContentIndex).
  set(RAID_V2.PRIMARY_TITLE, primaryTitle).
  set(RAID_V2.METADATA, jsonbMetadata).
  set(RAID_V2.METADATA_SCHEMA, mapJs2Jq(metadata.getMetadataSchema())).
  set(RAID_V2.START_DATE, startDate).
  set(RAID_V2.DATE_CREATED, LocalDateTime.now()).
  set(RAID_V2.CONFIDENTIAL, confidential).
  onConflict(RAID_V2.HANDLE).doUpdate().
    set(RAID_V2.SERVICE_POINT_ID, servicePointId).
    set(RAID_V2.URL, raidUrl).
    set(RAID_V2.URL_INDEX, urlContentIndex).
    set(RAID_V2.PRIMARY_TITLE, primaryTitle).
    set(RAID_V2.METADATA, jsonbMetadata).
    set(RAID_V2.METADATA_SCHEMA, mapJs2Jq(metadata.getMetadataSchema())).
    set(RAID_V2.START_DATE, startDate).
    set(RAID_V2.DATE_CREATED, LocalDateTime.now()).
    set(RAID_V2.CONFIDENTIAL, confidential).
    where(RAID_V2.HANDLE.eq(handle)).
  execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the PostgreSQL specific [`EXCLUDED` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html), which has been introduced in jOOQ 3.17:

- [#5214](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5214): Native support for the clause
- [#13571](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13571): Emulation of the clause in `MERGE`
- [#13575](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13575): Emulation of the clause inside of expressions (3.18)

For example:

```java
.onConflict(RAID_V2.HANDLE).doUpdate()
.set(RAID_V2.SERVICE_POINT_ID, excluded(RAID_V2.SERVICE_POINT_ID))
.set(RAID_V2.URL, excluded(RAID_V2.URL))
...
```

Or, if you're not too keen on repeating all the columns, just do it automatically, like this:

```java
.onConflict(RAID_V2.HANDLE).doUpdate()
.set(Arrays.stream(RAID_V2.fields())
           .filter(f -> !isKey(f)) // Exclude key columns, and others...
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f, f -> excluded(f))))
```

Note, while it probably doesn't apply to your specific case, in simpler cases, you could use `UpdatableRecord::merge` to simplify the upsert operation.